# Difference between Trade-off and Balance?

Tags: legalese

What is the difference between "Balance" and "Trade-off" ?
For instance at these two sentences:

```
Legal balance between rights and interests
```

And

```
Trade-offs between rights and interests
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly, but without further context it's impossible to say definitively.

Strictly speaking, a *trade-off* involves actually exchanging one thing to gain another. It's used metaphorically, too, and usually in the guise of a "win-win" for both parties.

In this context, a *legal balance* probably means that the courts will ensure that interests never outweigh legal rights.

Answer (score 0):

In 'balance', there would be a balance between the rights and interests.

In 'trade-off', may get whats asked for, but importantly, also had to give something up, make concession, make a compromise in order to get an agreement.